# How to uncheck Radio.Button v4 in React

Tags: reactjs, antd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMQCq.png)
Radio.Button

Comment: Please explain your problem more in detail and what you're trying to achieve. Also which research / testing you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best strategy would be use Checkbox instead of Radio button, as Radio are most commonly use with groups.

But if you really need to use Radio, here is what you can do

```js
...
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

return <Radio checked={checked} onClick={ () => setChecked(!checked) }>My radio</Radio>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Comment: my bad, will change the answer